# Extend UTF8 encode

Tags: c#, sockets, decode, encode

I'm trying to encode and decode a string. I realised that some characters are encoded as 2 bytes, some as 1 byte only. Is there a way to extend those 1 byte characters with leading zeros?

```
        public byte[] ToByte()
        {
            List<byte> result = new List<byte>();

            //First four are for the Command
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes((int)cmdCommand));

            //Add the length of the name
            if (strName != null)
                result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(strName.Length));
            else
                result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(0));

            //Length of the message
            if (strMessage != null)
                result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(strMessage.Length));
            else
                result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(0));

            //Console.WriteLine("name length: " + strName.Length + "  message length: " + strMessage.Length);

            //Add the name
            if (strName != null)
                result.AddRange(Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(strName));


            //And, lastly we add the message text to our array of bytes
            if (strMessage != null)
                result.AddRange(Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(strMessage));


            return result.ToArray();
        }
```

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: If you are sure that the content is in UTF8, why would not you just use `Encoding.UTF8.GetString()`?

Comment: No. Use a 16 bit encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just prefixing 1-byte characters with a 0-byte would not convert from UTF-8 to any usefull encoding I know.

And in addition UTF-8 is a 1, 2, 3 or 4 byte per character encoding (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). If you have as input an UTF-8 string and want to convert it to UTF-16 (this would be a true 2-byte per character encoding) you could use something like that:

```
var inputAsString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString (inputByteArray);
var utf16ByteArray = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding ("utf-16").GetBytes (inputAsString);
```

Here is a list of encodings you can use in .net https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding?view=net-6.0#list-of-encodings or you check with the following code which encodings are available on your system `System.Text.Encoding.GetEncodings ();`